# How to make individual table cells clickable? (Bootstrap and Slim Gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, slim-lang

I have a table, populated with many table cells with a class `'td.event'` , I want to ensure that each td is clickable, multiple times, that in turn triggers CSS changes via a other function.

I have the code below, but this results in the below Syntax error via Rails server upon loading the page.

```
syntax error, unexpected =>
```

Slim Attempt:

```
td.event
        == activity_cell.subtitle, :onclick => "classSetter()".html_safe
```

Javascript:

```
 javascript:
  function classSetter() {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('td.event'), i;
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
     divs[i].classList.add('unClicked');
  }};
```

Comment: When and where is the syntax error? Is it in your Rails server when you load the page, or in your console when you click on a `td`?

Comment: @JakeWorth Its in the rails server on page load.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but don't you want the onclick on the `td` itself, not the text that's inside of it?

Comment: @JakeWorth Yes exactly, I thought this was applying that, but being new to Slim perhaps not?